# A sci-fi/fantasy book about an author who gets sent into the world of his own books

Tags: story-identification

A few months ago I saw a sci-fi/fantasy novel. I can't remember the name but I know it was a recent book about a fantasy author who somehow gets transported into the world of his own books.

Comment: The following answer is wrong. However, I was immediately reminded of *Sophie's World* by Jostein Gaarder. If you haven't heard of it, it isn't a sci-fi novel, but more of a fictional gateway into philosophy.

Comment: Some more wrong answers: "Exile" by Edmond Hamilton, *Typewriter in the Sky* by L. Ron Hubbard, *What Mad Universe?* by Fredric Brown.

Comment: Could it perhaps be one of the Dark Tower series by Stephan King? I haven't read them myself but King somehow finds himself in the world and IIRC has some kind of influence over it.

Comment: No, it wasn't one of the Dark Tower books. And I checked I don't believe it was What Mad Universe or Typewriter In The Sky. This was a more recent book. It looked nearly brand new.

Comment: Anything else you remember? Description of the cover? Any character names?

Comment: I think there was a battle going on on the cover.

Comment: You still seem to be around intermittently. Could you mark your answer as accepted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually found out what the book was called. It was **"Dark Lord"**, part of the [Falconfar series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/59604-falconfar-saga) by Ed Greenwood.

> When he mysteriously finds himself drawn into a world of his own
>   devising, writer Rod Everlar is confronted by a shocking truth: he has
>   lost control of his creation to a brooding cabal of evil. In order to
>   save his creation - and himself - he must seize control of Falconfar
>   and halt the spread of corruption before it's too late.

I found it while looking through the science fiction section at Barnes & Noble, but thank you all for trying to help me. I appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Could it be **Inkheart** or another book of the [**Inkheart trilogy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart_trilogy)?

In short, it's about a guy who's able to read people in/out of books. So he's able to transfer himself or others into his own stories or out of them into the real world.

The catch is that the transfer happens in both ways. For one person to leave a book [another has to enter](http://kleinletters.com/Blog/and-then-i-read-inkdeath-by-cornelia-funke/) and vice versa.

> *All the Inkheart books, and especially INKDEATH are full of metafiction techniques. In the first book, Inkheart is also the title
>   of a book within the book. Mo, one of the main characters, has the
>   ability to bring characters from that book to life in “our” world when
>   he reads about them out loud, causing much of the plot. Eventually the
>   author of the book within the book is found and actually sent INTO his
>   own book!*

There also has been a [German movie adaption](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0494238/) (2008) of the first book a few years ago.

Answer (score -2):

The series you are asking about is from Terry Brooks and here they are.
The series is called "Landover":

- *Magic Kingdom for Sale–Sold!*
- *The Black Unicorn*
- *Wizard At Large*
- *The Tangle Box*
- *Witches’ Brew*
- *A Princess of Landover*
- An Untitled Final Book (forthcoming)

Comment: While it's certainly posible that Ben Holiday (the central character of the Landover books) is *based* on Terry Brooks, in the series he's a lawyer, not a writer, and didn't "create" Landover.